# Bibliography label width problem with multibib

Tags: labels, width, multibib

I'm trying to create a CV using `multibib` to cite articles together and conference presentations together.  I'm using the `plain` bibliography style and in the first set of citations, the bibliography entries are not sufficiently offset when the label gets to double digits.  The second set of citations are done the same way and they are correctly offset.

Here is the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{ref}{Refereed Publications}
\newcites{conf}{Conference Presentations}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large\textsc{Betty N. Love}}\\
\smallskip
%\it{3425 S. 115th St.}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \it{Omaha, NE 68144}\\
%\it{402-206-7844}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \it{betty.n.love@gmail.com}

\it{Department of Mathematics}\\
\it{University of Nebraska-Omaha}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \it{Omaha, NE 68144}\\
\it{402-206-7844}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \it{blove@unomaha.edu}
\end{center}
\bigskip

{\Large\bf Professional Profile}
\begin{itemize}
\item Extensive experience teaching mathematics, computing, and operations research at the undergraduate and graduate levels
\item Refereed publications in operations research, geographic information systems, mathematics and computer science pedagogy
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

{\Large\bf Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item {Ph.D., Operations Research}, Southern Methodist University, Dallas, TX, 1991
\item { M.S., Operations Research}, Southern Methodist University, Dallas, TX, 1988
\item { M.S., Mathematical Sciences}, Clemson University, Clemson, SC, 1986
\item { B.S., Mathematics}, University of Louisiana-Monroe, Monroe, LA, 1984
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

{\Large\bf Professional Experience}
\begin{itemize}
\item Associate Professor, Department of Mathematics, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1998-present
\item Associate Professor, Department of Information Systems and Quantitative Analysis, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1996-1998
\item Assistant Professor, Department of Computer Science, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1990-1996
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

\nociteref{winter:2016:tfpie}
\nociteref{winter:2016:fablearn}
\nociteref{love:2016:idc}
\nociteref{love:2015}
\nociteref{hodge:2014}
\nociteref{love:2014}
\nociteref{taylor:2014}
\nociteref{taylor:2012}
\nociteref{lipovetsky:2002}
\nociteref{bishop:1999}
\nociteref{corritore:1999}
\nociteref{bishop:1998}
\nociteref{dula:1997}
\nociteref{hickman:1997}
\nociteref{hickman:1995:computer}
\nociteref{hickman:1995:broadening}
\nociteref{hickman:1995:advanced}
\nociteref{hickman:1995:cutting}
\nociteref{barr:1994:reporting}
\nociteref{barr:1994:parallel}
\nociteref{sharif:1994}
\nociteref{elrewini:1994}
\nociteref{barr:1993:reporting}
\nociteref{barr:1993:using}
\nociteref{barr:1992}
\nociteref{dula:1992}
\nociteref{barr:1991}

\nociteconf{love:2016:maa}
\nociteconf{love:2016:nas}
\nociteconf{love:2015:informs}
\nociteconf{hickman:1998:informs}
\nociteconf{hickman:1997:informs}
\nociteconf{dula:1997:informs}
\nociteconf{dula:1996:informs}
\nociteconf{hickman:1996:csts}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:gis}
\nociteconf{dula:1995:belguim}
\nociteconf{barr:1995:informs}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:necc}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:orsa}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:negis}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:aag}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:ted}
\nociteconf{hickman:1995:peru}
\nociteconf{barr:1994:csor}
\nociteconf{hickman:1993:orsa0}
\nociteconf{hickman:1993:orsa1}
\nociteconf{barr:1991:orsa0}
\nociteconf{barr:1991:orsa1}
\nociteconf{barr:1990:orsa}
\nociteconf{barr:1989:orsa}
\nociteconf{barr:1989:cors}
\nociteconf{hickman:1989:cors}

\bibliographystyleref{plain}
\bibliographyref{lit}

\bibliographystyleconf{plain}
\bibliographyconf{lit}

\end{document}
```

Here's the `lit.bib` file:

```
%============================================================================================================
%Refereed Publications
%============================================================================================================


@article{love:2015,
    title   =   {Inquiry-Based Learning and the Flipped Classroom Model},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Angie Hodge and Cindy Corritore and Dana Ernst},
    journal =   {PRIMUS},
    volume  =   25,
    number  =   8,
    year        =   2015,
    pages   =   {745-762}
}

@incollection{hodge:2014,
    title       =   {A flipped classroom approach: Benefits and challenges of flipping the learning of procedural knowledge},
    author  =   {Angie Hodge and Betty Love and Neal Grandgenett and Andrew W. Swift},
    booktitle   =   {Online learning: Common misconceptions, benefits and challenges},
    editor  =   {P. R. Lowenthal and C. S. York and J. C. Richardson},
    publisher   =   {Nova Science Pub},
    year        =   {2014},
    pages   =   {49-60}
}

@article{love:2014,
    title   =   {Student learning and perceptions in a flipped linear algebra course},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Angie Hodge and Neal Grandgenett and Andrew W. Swift},
    journal =   {International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology},
    volume  =   45,
    number  =   3,
    year    =   2014,
    pages   =   {317-324}
}

@article{taylor:2014,
    title   =   {Simple multi-attribute rating technique for renewable energy deployment decisions (SMART REDD)},
    author  =   {James Taylor and Betty Love},
    journal =   {The Journal of Defense Modeling and Simulation: Applications, Methodology, Technology},
    volume  =   11,
    number  =   3,
    year    =   2014,
    pages   =   {227-232}
}

@inproceedings{taylor:2012,
    title       =   {Proof-of-concept for a green energy linear program for optimizing deployments},
    author      =   {James Taylor and Betty Love},
    booktitle   =   {The Proceedings of Defense and Military Modeling and Simulation Symposium (DMMS)},
    year        =   {2012},
    pages       =   {28-31}
}

@article{lipovetsky:2002,
    title   =   {Balanced Accuracy and Confidence Probability of Interval Estimates},
    author  =   {Stan Lipovetsky and Betty Hickman and Yi-Hsin Liu},
    journal =   {International Journal of Reliability and Applications},
    volume  =   {3},
    number  =   {1},
    year    =   {2002},
    pages   =   {37-50}
}

@article{bishop:1999,
    title   =   {SPOT panchromatic imagery and neural networks for information extraction in a complex mountain environment},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and John Shroder and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Geocarto International},
    volume  =   14,
    number  =   2,
    year    =   1999,
    pages   =   {19-28}
}

@article{bishop:1998,
    title   =   {Scale-dependent analysis of satellite imagery for characterization of glacier surfaces in the Karakoram Himalaya},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and John Shroder and Betty Hickman and Luke Copland},
    journal =   {Geomorphology},
    volume  =   21,
    number  =   3,
    year    =   1998,
    pages   =   {217-232}
}

@article{dula:1997,
    title   =   {Effects of excluding the column being scored from the DEA envelopment LP technology matrix},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume  =   48,
    number  =   10,
    year    =   1997,
    pages   =   {1001-1012}
}

@article{corritore:1999,
    title   =   {A Comparison of Two Laboratory-based Approaches for Teaching Introductory Computer Science},
    author  =   {Cindy Corritore and Betty Hickman and Neal Grandgenett and Rob Hitchcock},
    journal =   {Innovations in education and training international},
    volume  =   36,
    number  =   4,
    year    =   1999,
    pages   =   {292-301}
}

@article{hickman:1997,
    title   =   {A Subtree-Partitioning Algorithm for Inducing Parallelism in Network Simplex Dual Updates},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Dan Scott},
    journal =   {Computational Optimization and Applications},
    volume  =   7,
    number  =   2,
    year    =   1997,
    pages   =   {183-197}
}

@article{hickman:1995:computer,
    title   =   {Computer literacy: the next generation},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    journal =   {Computer Science Education},
    volume  =   6,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {49-66}
}

@article{hickman:1995:broadening,
    title   =   {Broadening the Scope: A new Approach to Computer Literacy Education},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    journal =   {Computers in Education Journal},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {55-63}
}

@article{hickman:1995:advanced,
    title   =   {Advanced computational methods for spatial information extraction},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Michael Bishop and Michael Rescigno},
    journal =   {Computers and Geosciences},
    volume  =   21,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {153-173}
}

@incollection{barr:1994:reporting,
    title       =   {Reporting on Parallel Software},
    author      =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Encyclopedia of Microcomputers},
    publisher   =   {Marcel Dekker},
    address     =   {New York},
    editor      =   {Allen Kent and James Williams},
    volume      =   15,
    year        =   1995,
    pages       =   {1-32}
}

@article{barr:1994:parallel,
    title   =   {Parallel simplex for large pure network problems: Computational testing and sources of speedup},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Operations Research},
    volume  =   42,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1994,
    pages   =   {65-80}
}

@article{barr:1993:reporting,
    title   =   {Reporting computational experiments with parallel algorithms: Issues, measures, and experts' opinions},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   { ORSA Journal on Computing},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1993,
    pages   =   {2-18}
}

@article{barr:1993:using,
    title   =   {Using Parallel Empirical Testing to Advance Algorithm Research},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {ORSA Journal on Computing},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1993,
    pages   =   {29-32}
}

@incollection{barr:1992,
    title       =   {On Reporting the Speedup of Parallel Algorithms: A Survey of Issues and Experts},
    author      =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Computer Science and Operations Research: New Developments in their Interfaces},
    publisher   =   {Pergamon Press},
    editor      =   {O. Balci and R. Sharda and S. Zenios},
    address     =   {Oxford, U.K},
    year        =   1992,
    pages       =   {279-294}
}

@incollection{dula:1992,
    title       =   {Preprocessing Schemes and a Solution Method for the Convex Hull Problem in a Multidimensional Space},
    author      =   {Jose Dula and Richard Helgason and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Computer Science and Operations Research: New Developments in their Interfaces},
    publisher   =   {Pergamon Press},
    editor      =   {O. Balci and R. Sharda and S. Zenios},
    address     =   {Oxford, U.K},
    year        =   1992,
    pages       =   {59-70}
}


%============================================================================================================
%Refereed Conference Proceedings
%============================================================================================================

@inproceedings{winter:2016:tfpie,
    title       =   {The Bricklayer Ecosystem - Art, Math, and Code},
    author  =   {Victor Winter and Betty Love and Cindy Corritore},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the 5th International Workshop on Trends in Functional Programming in Education},
    year        =   {2016}
}


@inproceedings{winter:2016:fablearn,
    title       =   {The Art of the Wunderlich Cube and the Development of Spatial Abilities},
    author  =   {Victor Winter and Betty Love and Cindy Corritore},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of FabLearn Europe},
    year        =   {2016}
}

@inproceedings{love:2016:idc,
    title           =   {Creating an Environment in which Elementary Educators Can Teach Coding},
    author      =   {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Cindy Corritore and Davina Faimon},
    booktitle       =   {Proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Interaction Design and Children},
    year            =   {2016},
    organization    =   {ACM}
}

@inproceedings{hickman:1995:cutting,
    title       =   {Cutting-Edge Technology in the Computer Literacy Classroom.},
    author      =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the 12th International Conference on Technology and Education},
    address     =   {Orlando},
    year        =   1995
}

@inproceedings{sharif:1994,
    title       =   {Design and Analysis of a Serial Link Interconnection Network Architecture},
    author      =   {Hamid Sharif and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the Seventh International Conference on Parallel and Distributed Computing Systems},
    address     =   {Las Vegas},
    year        =   1994
}

@inproceedings{elrewini:1994,
    title       =   {Teaching Parallel Computing by Exploring Various Programming Paradigms},
    author      =   {Hesham {El-Rewini} and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the Conference on Parallel Computing for Undergraduates},
    address     =   {Colgate University},
    year        =   1994
}

@inproceedings{barr:1991,
    title       =   {Enhancing Incomplete Policy Research Databases via Fuzzy Record Matching},
    author      =   {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
    booktitle   =   {North American Fuzzy Information Processing Society 1991 Workshop Proceedings},
    year        =   1991
}








%============================================================================================================
%Conference Presentations
%============================================================================================================

@unpublished{love:2016:maa,
    title   =   {Bricklayer Coding as a Vehicle for Learning Math},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Davina Faimon},
    note    =   {MAA Section Meeting, Concordia University},
    year    =   2016
}


@unpublished{love:2016:nas,
    title   =   {Bricklayer Coding as a Vehicle for Learning Math},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Davina Faimon},
    note    =   {Nebraska Academy of Science, Nebraska Wesleyan University},
    year    =   2016
}


@unpublished{love:2015:informs,
    title   =   {Optimization of Resource Use In Massively Multiplayer Online Games},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Andrew Cockerill},
    note    =   {INFORMS, Philadelphia},
    year    =   2015
}

@unpublished{hickman:1998:informs,
    title   =   {Web-Based Data Envelopment Analysis},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Jose Dula and Cindy Corritore and Arunachalam Ravichandran},
    note    =   {CORS/INFORMS, Montreal},
    year    =   1998
}

@unpublished{hickman:1997:informs,
    title   =   {Applications of Intelligent Agents in Information Systems},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cindy Corritore and Dan Peak},
    note    =   {INFORMS, San Diego},
    year    =   1997
}

@unpublished{dula:1997:informs,
    title   =   {Opportunistic Schemes for Computational Enhancements in DEA},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {INFORMS, San Diego},
    year    =   1997
}

@unpublished{dula:1996:informs,
    title   =   {New Algorithms for DEA},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {INFORMS, Washington},
    year    =   1996
}

@unpublished{hickman:1996:csts,
    title   =   {A Linear Programming Approach to Terrestrial Imaging Spectroscopy Data Analysis},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Richard Barr and Michael Bishop and Cindy Corritore and Fred Glover},
    note    =   {INFORMS CSTS Conference, Dallas },
    year    =   1996
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:gis,
    title   =   {DEMETER: A Prototype Spatial Analysis Software System},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Michael Bishop and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore},
    note    =   {GIS/LIS, Nashville},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{dula:1995:belguim,
    title   =   {Effects of Excluding the Column Being Scored from the DEA Envelopment LP Technology Matrix},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {Fourth European Workshop on Efficiency and Productivity Measurement, Center for Operations Research and Econometrics, Louvain-La-Neuve, Belgium},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{barr:1995:informs,
    title   =   {Statistical File Merging: A New Constrained-Network Model and Parallel Solution Approach},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {INFORMS, New Orleans},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:necc,
    title   =   {Closed Laboratories and Alternatives for Introductory Computer Science Courses},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cindy Corritore and Neal Grandgenett and Rob Hitchcock},
    note    =   {National Education Computing Conference, Baltimore},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:orsa,
    title   =   {Advances in Parallel Network Simplex Implementations},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Dan Scott},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Los Angeles},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:negis,
    title   =   {DEMETER--Distributed Modeling Technology for Earth Resources},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and Betty Love and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore and J Raspotnik and J Ward},
    note    =   {Nebraska GIS Forum, Lincoln},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:aag,
    title   =   {Spatial Analysis and Modeling using Object Oriented Technology},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and Betty Love and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore and J Raspotnik and J Ward},
    note    =   {American Association of Geographers National Meeting, Chicago},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:ted,
    title   =   {Cutting-Edge Technology in the Computer Literacy Classroom},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    note    =   {12th Annual International Conference on Technology in Education, Orlando },
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:peru,
    title   =   {Computer Literacy for the 90's: New Strategies for Teaching a Changing Topic},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    note    =   {Nebraska Faculty College Conference, Peru State College},
    year    =   1994
}

@unpublished{barr:1994:csor,
    title   =   {Optimal Microdatabase Merging: A New Method and Applications},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {Computer Science and Operations Research: The Impact of Emerging Technology Conference},
    year    =   1994
}

@unpublished{hickman:1993:orsa0,
    title   =   {A Parallel Algorithm for the Convex Hull Problem},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Sheri Zimmel},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Phoenix},
    year    =   1993
}

@unpublished{hickman:1993:orsa1,
    title   =   {The Effect of Processor Speed on Speedup},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Chicago},
    year    =   1993
}

@unpublished{barr:1991:orsa0,
    title   =   {Parallel Primal Network Simplex: An Empirical Study of the Algorithms's Temporal Behavior},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Anaheim},
    year    =   1991
}

@unpublished{barr:1991:orsa1,
    title   =   {A Parallel Optimization Code for Large Networks with Side Conditions: Statistical File Merging Applications},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Nashville},
    year    =   1991
}

@unpublished{barr:1990:orsa,
    title   =   {A Parallel Approach to Large-Scale Network Models with Side Conditions},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Philadelphia},
    year    =   1990
}

@unpublished{barr:1989:orsa,
    title   =   {On Reporting the Speedup of Parallel Algorithms},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, New York},
    year    =   1989
}

@unpublished{barr:1989:cors,
    title   =   {New Network Optimization Approaches to Statistical File Merging},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {CORS/ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Vancouver},
    year    =   1989
}

@unpublished{hickman:1989:cors,
    title   =   {Parallelization Strategies for the Network Simplex Algorithm},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {CORS/ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Vancouver},
    year    =   1989
}
```

Both `conf.bbl` and `ref.bbl` begin with

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
```

Q1: How can I fix the label width problem?

Q2: The left margin for the text before the bibliography is larger than that of the bibliography.  How can I make the left margin uniform for the whole document?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  I use TexShop on my mac.  It's v 3.6.2.  I did the following: 558  latex vita
  559  bibtex vita
  560  bibtex ref
  561  bibtex conf
  562  latex vita
  563  latex vita

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your code I see several problems, for example do not use `\it` or `\bf`, they are outdated for a long time.  I guess you are using a template from the internet?  Seems to be a very old one ...

Your code causes that first lines of the paragraphs are intendent.  That is the reason your headlines are intended. To avoid that you need to use command `\noindent` like:

```
\noindent{\Large \textbf{Professional Profile}} % <=====================
```

Perhaps it would be better to use `\section` or `\section*` ?

**Now to package `multibib`:**

I would create two bib files, one for your "ref"s, one for your "conf"s ...

Follwing the documentation to package `multibib` (try `texdoc multibib` on your console/terminal) one bib file be the usual one (see example on page 4).

Your problem with the labelwith can be corrected with command `\setbiblabelwidth{10}` in your case (see documentation page 2).

Please see the following MWE (important changes marked with `<==========`)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{321754-ref.bib}
@inproceedings{barr:1991,
  title     = {Enhancing Incomplete Policy Research Databases via Fuzzy Record Matching},
  author    = {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
  booktitle = {North American Fuzzy Information Processing Society 1991 Workshop Proceedings},
  year      = 1991,
}
@incollection{dula:1992,
  title     = {Preprocessing Schemes and a Solution Method for the Convex Hull Problem in a Multidimensional Space},
  author    = {Jose Dula and Richard Helgason and Betty Hickman},
  booktitle = {Computer Science and Operations Research: New Developments in their Interfaces},
  publisher = {Pergamon Press},
  editor    = {O. Balci and R. Sharda and S. Zenios},
  address   = {Oxford, U.K},
  year      = 1992,
  pages     = {59--70},
}
@incollection{hodge:2014,
    title   =   {A flipped classroom approach: Benefits and challenges of flipping the learning of procedural knowledge},
    author  =   {Angie Hodge and Betty Love and Neal Grandgenett and Andrew W. Swift},
    booktitle   =   {Online learning: Common misconceptions, benefits and challenges},
    editor  =   {P. R. Lowenthal and C. S. York and J. C. Richardson},
    publisher   =   {Nova Science Pub},
    year        =   {2014},
    pages   =   {49--60},
}
@article{lipovetsky:2002,
  title   = {Balanced Accuracy and Confidence Probability of Interval Estimates},
  author  = {Stan Lipovetsky and Betty Hickman and Yi-Hsin Liu},
  journal = {International Journal of Reliability and Applications},
  volume  = {3},
  number  = {1},
  year    = {2002},
  pages   = {37--50},
}
@article{love:2014,
  title   = {Student learning and perceptions in a flipped linear algebra course},
  author  = {Betty Love and Angie Hodge and Neal Grandgenett and Andrew W. Swift},
  journal = {International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology},
  volume  = 45,
  number  = 3,
  year    = 2014,
  pages   = {317--324},
}
@article{love:2015,
  title   = {Inquiry-Based Learning and the Flipped Classroom Model},
  author  = {Betty Love and Angie Hodge and Cindy Corritore and Dana Ernst},
  journal = {PRIMUS},
  volume  = 25,
  number  = 8,
  year    = 2015,
  pages   = {745--762},
}
@inproceedings{love:2016:idc,
  title        = {Creating an Environment in which Elementary Educators Can Teach Coding},
  author       = {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Cindy Corritore and Davina Faimon},
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Interaction Design and Children},
  year         = {2016},
  organization = {ACM},
}
@inproceedings{taylor:2012,
  title     = {Proof-of-concept for a green energy linear program for optimizing deployments},
  author    = {James Taylor and Betty Love},
  booktitle = {The Proceedings of Defense and Military Modeling and Simulation Symposium (DMMS)},
  year      = {2012},
  pages     = {28--31},
}
@article{taylor:2014,
  title   = {Simple multi-attribute rating technique for renewable energy deployment decisions (SMART REDD)},
  author  = {James Taylor and Betty Love},
  journal = {The Journal of Defense Modeling and Simulation: Applications, Methodology, Technology},
  volume  = 11,
  number  = 3,
  year    = 2014,
  pages   = {227--232},
}
@inproceedings{winter:2016:tfpie,
  title     = {The Bricklayer Ecosystem - Art, Math, and Code},
  author    = {Victor Winter and Betty Love and Cindy Corritore},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 5th International Workshop on 
               Trends in Functional Programming in Education},
  year      = {2016},
}
@inproceedings{winter:2016:fablearn,
  title     = {The Art of the Wunderlich Cube and the Development of Spatial Abilities},
  author    = {Victor Winter and Betty Love and Cindy Corritore},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of FabLearn Europe},
  year      = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bishop:1999,
    title   =   {SPOT panchromatic imagery and neural networks for information extraction in a complex mountain environment},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and John Shroder and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Geocarto International},
    volume  =   14,
    number  =   2,
    year    =   1999,
    pages   =   {19--28},
}

@article{bishop:1998,
    title   =   {Scale-dependent analysis of satellite imagery for characterization of glacier surfaces in the Karakoram Himalaya},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and John Shroder and Betty Hickman and Luke Copland},
    journal =   {Geomorphology},
    volume  =   21,
    number  =   3,
    year    =   1998,
    pages   =   {217-232}
}

@article{dula:1997,
    title   =   {Effects of excluding the column being scored from the DEA envelopment LP technology matrix},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
    volume  =   48,
    number  =   10,
    year    =   1997,
    pages   =   {1001-1012}
}

@article{corritore:1999,
    title   =   {A Comparison of Two Laboratory-based Approaches for Teaching Introductory Computer Science},
    author  =   {Cindy Corritore and Betty Hickman and Neal Grandgenett and Rob Hitchcock},
    journal =   {Innovations in education and training international},
    volume  =   36,
    number  =   4,
    year    =   1999,
    pages   =   {292-301}
}

@article{hickman:1997,
    title   =   {A Subtree-Partitioning Algorithm for Inducing Parallelism in Network Simplex Dual Updates},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Dan Scott},
    journal =   {Computational Optimization and Applications},
    volume  =   7,
    number  =   2,
    year    =   1997,
    pages   =   {183-197}
}

@article{hickman:1995:computer,
    title   =   {Computer literacy: the next generation},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    journal =   {Computer Science Education},
    volume  =   6,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {49-66}
}

@article{hickman:1995:broadening,
    title   =   {Broadening the Scope: A new Approach to Computer Literacy Education},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    journal =   {Computers in Education Journal},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {55-63}
}

@article{hickman:1995:advanced,
    title   =   {Advanced computational methods for spatial information extraction},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Michael Bishop and Michael Rescigno},
    journal =   {Computers and Geosciences},
    volume  =   21,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1995,
    pages   =   {153-173}
}

@incollection{barr:1994:reporting,
    title       =   {Reporting on Parallel Software},
    author      =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Encyclopedia of Microcomputers},
    publisher   =   {Marcel Dekker},
    address     =   {New York},
    editor      =   {Allen Kent and James Williams},
    volume      =   15,
    year        =   1995,
    pages       =   {1-32}
}

@article{barr:1994:parallel,
    title   =   {Parallel simplex for large pure network problems: Computational testing and sources of speedup},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {Operations Research},
    volume  =   42,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1994,
    pages   =   {65-80}
}

@article{barr:1993:reporting,
    title   =   {Reporting computational experiments with parallel algorithms: Issues, measures, and experts' opinions},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   { ORSA Journal on Computing},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1993,
    pages   =   {2-18}
}

@article{barr:1993:using,
    title   =   {Using Parallel Empirical Testing to Advance Algorithm Research},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    journal =   {ORSA Journal on Computing},
    volume  =   5,
    number  =   1,
    year    =   1993,
    pages   =   {29--32},
}

@incollection{barr:1992,
    title       =   {On Reporting the Speedup of Parallel Algorithms: A Survey of Issues and Experts},
    author      =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Computer Science and Operations Research: New Developments in their Interfaces},
    publisher   =   {Pergamon Press},
    editor      =   {O. Balci and R. Sharda and S. Zenios},
    address     =   {Oxford, U.K},
    year        =   1992,
    pages       =   {279--294},
}

@inproceedings{hickman:1995:cutting,
    title       =   {Cutting-Edge Technology in the Computer Literacy Classroom.},
    author      =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the 12th International Conference on Technology and Education},
    address     =   {Orlando},
    year        =   1995
}

@inproceedings{sharif:1994,
    title       =   {Design and Analysis of a Serial Link Interconnection Network Architecture},
    author      =   {Hamid Sharif and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the Seventh International Conference on Parallel and Distributed Computing Systems},
    address     =   {Las Vegas},
    year        =   1994
}

@inproceedings{elrewini:1994,
    title       =   {Teaching Parallel Computing by Exploring Various Programming Paradigms},
    author      =   {Hesham {El-Rewini} and Betty Hickman},
    booktitle   =   {Proceedings of the Conference on Parallel Computing for Undergraduates},
    address     =   {Colgate University},
    year        =   1994
}

@unpublished{love:2016:maa,
    title   =   {Bricklayer Coding as a Vehicle for Learning Math},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Davina Faimon},
    note    =   {MAA Section Meeting, Concordia University},
    year    =   2016,
}

@unpublished{love:2016:nas,
    title   =   {Bricklayer Coding as a Vehicle for Learning Math},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Victor Winter and Davina Faimon},
    note    =   {Nebraska Academy of Science, Nebraska Wesleyan University},
    year    =   2016
}

@unpublished{love:2015:informs,
    title   =   {Optimization of Resource Use In Massively Multiplayer Online Games},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Andrew Cockerill},
    note    =   {INFORMS, Philadelphia},
    year    =   2015
}

@unpublished{hickman:1998:informs,
    title   =   {Web-Based Data Envelopment Analysis},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Jose Dula and Cindy Corritore and Arunachalam Ravichandran},
    note    =   {CORS/INFORMS, Montreal},
    year    =   1998
}

@unpublished{hickman:1997:informs,
    title   =   {Applications of Intelligent Agents in Information Systems},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cindy Corritore and Dan Peak},
    note    =   {INFORMS, San Diego},
    year    =   1997
}

@unpublished{dula:1997:informs,
    title   =   {Opportunistic Schemes for Computational Enhancements in DEA},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {INFORMS, San Diego},
    year    =   1997
}

@unpublished{dula:1996:informs,
    title   =   {New Algorithms for DEA},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {INFORMS, Washington},
    year    =   1996
}

@unpublished{hickman:1996:csts,
    title   =   {A Linear Programming Approach to Terrestrial Imaging Spectroscopy Data Analysis},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Richard Barr and Michael Bishop and Cindy Corritore and Fred Glover},
    note    =   {INFORMS CSTS Conference, Dallas },
    year    =   1996
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:gis,
    title   =   {DEMETER: A Prototype Spatial Analysis Software System},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Michael Bishop and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore},
    note    =   {GIS/LIS, Nashville},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{dula:1995:belguim,
    title   =   {Effects of Excluding the Column Being Scored from the DEA Envelopment LP Technology Matrix},
    author  =   {Jose Dula and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {Fourth European Workshop on Efficiency and Productivity Measurement, Center for Operations Research and Econometrics, Louvain-La-Neuve, Belgium},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{barr:1995:informs,
    title   =   {Statistical File Merging: A New Constrained-Network Model and Parallel Solution Approach},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {INFORMS, New Orleans},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:necc,
    title   =   {Closed Laboratories and Alternatives for Introductory Computer Science Courses},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cindy Corritore and Neal Grandgenett and Rob Hitchcock},
    note    =   {National Education Computing Conference, Baltimore},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:orsa,
    title   =   {Advances in Parallel Network Simplex Implementations},
    author  =   {Betty Love and Dan Scott},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Los Angeles},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:negis,
    title   =   {DEMETER--Distributed Modeling Technology for Earth Resources},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and Betty Love and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore and J Raspotnik and J Ward},
    note    =   {Nebraska GIS Forum, Lincoln},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:aag,
    title   =   {Spatial Analysis and Modeling using Object Oriented Technology},
    author  =   {Michael Bishop and Betty Love and Todd Munson and Cindy Corritore and J Raspotnik and J Ward},
    note    =   {American Association of Geographers National Meeting, Chicago},
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:ted,
    title   =   {Cutting-Edge Technology in the Computer Literacy Classroom},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    note    =   {12th Annual International Conference on Technology in Education, Orlando },
    year    =   1995
}

@unpublished{hickman:1995:peru,
    title   =   {Computer Literacy for the 90's: New Strategies for Teaching a Changing Topic},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Cynthia Corritore},
    note    =   {Nebraska Faculty College Conference, Peru State College},
    year    =   1994
}

@unpublished{barr:1994:csor,
    title   =   {Optimal Microdatabase Merging: A New Method and Applications},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Love and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {Computer Science and Operations Research: The Impact of Emerging Technology Conference},
    year    =   1994
}

@unpublished{hickman:1993:orsa0,
    title   =   {A Parallel Algorithm for the Convex Hull Problem},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman and Sheri Zimmel},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Phoenix},
    year    =   1993
}

@unpublished{hickman:1993:orsa1,
    title   =   {The Effect of Processor Speed on Speedup},
    author  =   {Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Chicago},
    year    =   1993
}

@unpublished{barr:1991:orsa0,
    title   =   {Parallel Primal Network Simplex: An Empirical Study of the Algorithms's Temporal Behavior},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Anaheim},
    year    =   1991
}

@unpublished{barr:1991:orsa1,
    title   =   {A Parallel Optimization Code for Large Networks with Side Conditions: Statistical File Merging Applications},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Nashville},
    year    =   1991,
}
@unpublished{barr:1990:orsa,
    title   =   {A Parallel Approach to Large-Scale Network Models with Side Conditions},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Philadelphia},
    year    =   1990,
}
@unpublished{barr:1989:orsa,
    title   =   {On Reporting the Speedup of Parallel Algorithms},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, New York},
    year    =   1989,
}
@unpublished{barr:1989:cors,
    title   =   {New Network Optimization Approaches to Statistical File Merging},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman and Scott Turner},
    note    =   {CORS/ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Vancouver},
    year    =   1989,
}
@unpublished{hickman:1989:cors,
    title   =   {Parallelization Strategies for the Network Simplex Algorithm},
    author  =   {Richard Barr and Betty Hickman},
    note    =   {CORS/ORSA/TIMS Joint Meeting, Vancouver},
    year    =   1989,
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================

\usepackage[%
  resetlabels, 
% labeled      % adds ref to label bib item
]{multibib}
\newcites{ref}{Refereed Publications}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Conference Presentations} % <===================


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large\textsc{Betty N. Love}}\\
\smallskip

\emph{Department of Mathematics}\\
\emph{University of Nebraska-Omaha}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \emph{Omaha, NE 68144}\\
\emph{402-206-7844}\ {\small$\bullet$}\ \emph{blove@unomaha.edu}
\end{center}
\bigskip

\noindent{\Large \textbf{Professional Profile}} % <=====================
\begin{itemize}
\item Extensive experience teaching mathematics, computing, and operations research at the undergraduate and graduate levels
\item Refereed publications in operations research, geographic information systems, mathematics and computer science pedagogy
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

{\Large \textbf{Education}}
\begin{itemize}
\item {Ph.D., Operations Research}, Southern Methodist University, Dallas, TX, 1991
\item { M.S., Operations Research}, Southern Methodist University, Dallas, TX, 1988
\item { M.S., Mathematical Sciences}, Clemson University, Clemson, SC, 1986
\item { B.S., Mathematics}, University of Louisiana-Monroe, Monroe, LA, 1984
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

{\Large \textbf{Professional Experience}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Associate Professor, Department of Mathematics, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1998-present
\item Associate Professor, Department of Information Systems and Quantitative Analysis, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1996-1998
\item Assistant Professor, Department of Computer Science, University of Nebraska-Omaha, 1990-1996
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

\nociteref{*} 
\bibliographystyleref{plain}
\bibliographyref{321754-ref} % \jobname = 321754 in my case


 \nocite{love:2016:maa} % instead of your lots of \nociteconf{...}
 \nocite{love:2016:nas}
 \nocite{love:2015:informs}
 \nocite{hickman:1998:informs}
 \nocite{hickman:1997:informs}
 \nocite{dula:1997:informs}
 \nocite{dula:1996:informs}
 \nocite{hickman:1996:csts}
 \nocite{hickman:1995:gis}
 \nocite{dula:1995:belguim}
 \nocite{barr:1995:informs}


%\nocite{*}             % add all entrys of bib file to bibliography
\setbiblabelwidth{10} % <===============================================
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pages:

[image: right format of headline]

and the bibliography:

[image: bibliography]